# Can't understand this code?

Tags: c++, function, comma-operator

Can anyone help me in understanding the following code:-

```
int r, countIt(int n) {
    while (r += "            2  "[n % 10] & 3, n /= 10);
    return r;
}
```

I found this code in one of the challenges of codefights.com, https://codefights.com/challenge/v5Zg8trjoun3PTxrZ/solutions/Aj3ppbhSShixt4nBi

This is a solution for counting number of holes in a number.
e.g.

```
1111 = 0  
0000 = 4  
1234 = 0  
8888 = 8
```

I am not able to understand the following things:
1. Logic of this code
2. comma (,) operator used in return data type of the function
3. Use of []operator after string.
4. And actually the whole code.

Comment: It's just two declarations combined together. Just like `int x, y;` is equivalent to `int x; int y;`, the code you show is equivalent to `int r; int countIt(int n) { ... }`. Merging variable definition and function definition like that only serves to confuse; don't do that in your code, however cool it may look once explained.

Comment: Wow, that is fairly clever. Horrible, yet funny. :)

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik. And that string part?

Comment: 3) You can have a string literal and use `operator []` on it.  for example: `"abcdef"[2]` will return `c`.

Comment: A string is basically an array of `char`, and an array followed by `[3]` is the fourth element of the array. So in this case it takes the last digit of `n`, puls out the corresponding character from the string, and then passes that to a logical operator. Oh, my head...

Comment: that would behave rather unhelpfully if you called countIt twice wouldn't it?

Also shouldn't that string have a few 1s in it?

Comment: Why isn't '4' considered to have a hole in it?

Comment: @James It is considered to have a hole in it - one of test cases is `1234` having one hole (presumably attributed to `4`).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik At least where I'm looking, the expected output of 1234 is 0. Unless 4 doesn't count because it's a 'corner case' as suggested in the question. Sneaky

Comment: @James You are right, 4 isn't considered to have a hole in it. Sorry for that

Comment: @James The question has been edited. The original version had `1234 = 1` line, which was the version I remembered. Anyway, it doesn't really matter much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up the link you provided. After carefully observing the code i came to following conclusion.

```
int r, countIt(int n) {.....}
```

is equivalent to writing as

```
int r;
int countIt(int n){.....}
```

now for

```
while (r += "            2  "[n % 10] & 3, n /= 10);
```

is equivalent to:

```
do{
    r += "           2  "[n % 10] & 3;
    n/=10;
}while(n);
```

Now comes the logical part of the code

```
r += "           2  "[n % 10] & 3;
```

let me give you some basics.

1. In c++

`cout<<"abcde"[2];`

will give you output

```
c
```

now if you watch carefully the code in link which you provided
its something like this:

```
r += "           2  "[n % 10] & 3;
```

is nothing but

```
r += "TAB,SPACE,SPACE,SPACE,SPACE,SPACE,TAB,SPACE,2,TAB"[n % 10] & 3;
```

Now its time to explain how this code is calculating number of holes.
The ASCII value of TAB is 9 whose binary equivalent is 1001.
The ASCII value of SPACE is 32 whose binary equivalent is 100000.

so bit wise anding TAB with 3 will result

```
            1001 & 0011 = 0001    which is 1
```

bit wise anding SPACE with 3 will result

```
            100000 & 000011 = 000000   which is 0
```

replacing TABs with 1 and SPACEs with 0 hence this concludes as writing

```
do{
    r += "1000001021"[n % 10] & 3;
    n/=10;
}while(n);
```

n % 10 is the low-order decimal digit of n. We use that as an index into a string literal, which contains information about how many holes is there in that low-order decimal digit then add it to result r.

Comment: One more thing. Variable r is global or local?

Comment: yep its global variable.

Answer (score 9):

Is that some kind of [obfuscated C contest](http://www.ioccc.org/) submission? Or [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)?

---

First, the weird declaration. It's just combining two unrelated declarations on one line. Just as

```
int x, y;
```

is equivalent to

```
int x;
int y;
```

so is your code equivalent to

```
int r;
int countIt(int n) {...}
```

It's a little known and, thankfully, little used quirk of the C grammar that you can do that.

---

The loop would become clearer if written this way:

```
do {
  r += "            2  "[n % 10] & 3;
  n /= 10;
} while (n);
```

It basically iterates over digits in the decimal representation of `n`.

---

Now the part of `r += "            2  "[n % 10] & 3;`. `n % 10` is the low-order decimal digit of `n`. We use that as an index into a string literal (which is just an array of `char`s), then extract two low-order bits of the character's ASCII code and discard the rest. I'm pretty sure that, in the original program you copied this code from, the characters in that literal were not spaces, but rather certain unprintable characters chosen in such a way that the two low-order bits of their ASCII codes gave precisely the number of "holes" in the corresponding digit. `2` character is a red-herring - it's in position 12, but only characters  0 through 9 are actually used.

In other words, this part can be more clearly written this way:

```
static const int numHoles[10] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1};
int digit = n % 10;
r += numHoles[digit];
```

---

Put together, we have:

```
int countIt(int n) {
  // number of holes in digit      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
  static const int numHoles[10] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1};
  int r = 0;
  do {
    int digit = n % 10;
    r += numHoles[digit];
    n /= 10;
  } while (n);
  return r;
};
```

Comment: I actually looked at the link he gave, and it appears the answer he is looking t does have spaces, as it fails most of the tests.

Comment: @TomTanner Probably worked on the orignal author's machine, but those unprintable characters didn't make it through when copy/pasted into a browser. Too clever by half.

Comment: They are not spaces, it just looks like it.

Comment: @James Well, they are spaces in the HTML source of this page. It's possible - likely, even - that they started life as something else, but by the time they ended up here, they certainly became plain spaces aka `'\x20'`.

Answer (score 0):

Using special chars in browsers can be a problem, from [Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) we can use all chars that in octal ends in 0 to 2 or 4 to 6, using those 2 bits to know how many holes the number have (`% 3` is the same as `% 0b11`, an and with the last 2 bits).

One solution with ascii chars is:

```
int countIt(int n) {
    int r;
    while (r += "1000101021"[n % 10] & 3, n /= 10);
    return r;
}
```

Instead of "0" to "2", i could use something like this:

```
int countIt(int n) {
    int r;
    while (r += "! X0) I@*9"[n % 10] & 3, n /= 10);
    return r;
}
```

I don't know what chars he tried to use, but didn't work in the challenge website.